# Login Failed for User when trying to connect to SQL Server 2012 from VB.net 2015

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, connection-string

I am trying to run my vb.net code (2015) in debug on my local machine and I am trying to connect to the SQL Server 2012 database that is on the same machine but no matter what I do, I keeping getting login failed for TestUser.

Here is my connection string -

```
<appsettings>
    <add key="Test_Conn" 
         value="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SP_Dev;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Test_Connect;Password=Tester123" />
</appsettings>
```

I am stumped as to why I cannot connect?

Comment: Your connection string says the user is `Test_Connect`, but you say it failed for `TestUser` - are you sure there's not another connection string being used?

Comment: That is a typo on my part.

Comment: I needed to change the server authentication from Windows to SQL Server and Windows!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the server authentication from Windows to SQL Server and Windows. This resolved my issue.